# WPF ListBox insert

Tags: wpf, listbox, insert, mode

I have a WPF Listbox defined in a DataTemplate that has its ItemsSource bound to an ObservableCollection. When new items are added to the collection, I want the ListBox to work in "insert mode", always adding to the front of the list, not the default append mode.
How do I make the ListBox use the insert mode when not adding to it directly in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Insert` method of the `ObservableCollection` and pass the index 0 - that will add it to the beginning of the collection.